# Why use MPI_File_open instead of fopen?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

After reading the MPI documentation, it doesn't sound like this gives you any additional functionality at all.  I had assumed that it coordinated network traffic such that all file operations work with the given file on the executing system (the one issuing an mpirun command), as opposed to using the local filesystem on each individual host.  This would be useful.  Instead, the "user" needs to ensure that they all end up at the same file.  Clearly they're not communicating that much about this file... are they?

What does MPI_File_open actually do, and how is it beneficial?  Why should I not just use fopen?

Comment: Uhhh ... if you aren't using MPI collective I/O then you probably dont need MPI file.  It sounds like you misunderstand MPI I/O - it is meant to work with distributed file on a parallel FS, eg NFS, Lustre, not to coordinate access to a file on one node.

Comment: I certainly do misunderstand it, that's why I'm asking :)  Care to elaborate in an answer?  I still don't get the use case.  Are you saying it's for extremely low level manual striping of files?  Are you saying it's for writing to different instances of the same file, which are later merged by an external system?  Something else?

Comment: The striping should happen below MPI I/O level.  Basically you need a parallel FS (Lustre, PVFS, etc) running, without it you cant do much.  You also must make sure MPI/FS are aware of each other.  Then the file created with MPI_File_open will be a single entity, visible (read/write) across all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, MPI_File_open allows you to seek and read/write at particular blocks, like you would with fopen, in which case each process has a private file pointer.  Differences from fopen include the nonblocking IO methods would allow your program to continue execution without waiting for the operation to complete. MPI also supports shared file pointers (e.g. MPI_File_read_shared), although obviously use of shared pointers have a synchronization overhead.